# MySql - Get all occurring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySql DB.
My main table is all the sentences of a series of 5 books, with indexes for the book, chapter in book, sentence in chapter.

Example - For Harry Potter book five, chapter 1 , sentence 3 I'll have a row like that.

```
BookID   ChapterID   SentenceID   Text
   4         1           3          Deprived of their usual car-washing and lawn-mowing pursuits, the inhabitants of Privet Drive had retreated into the shade of their cool houses, windows thrown wide in the hope of tempting in a nonexistent breeze.
```

I need to retrieve all the occurrence of a letter or a word.
So if I search for 'e' I'll get the same row 17 times. 'e' occur 17 time in this row.

I've simplified the scenario, I have more information to retrieve for each letter.

So far I've been unable to get something useful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm 90% certain an SQL query won't return more than one row for a given database row, unless you use a JOIN. But that would be very inefficient for your purposes.

The way this would typically be implemented is using a query like `SELECT * FROM books WHERE Text LIKE '%e%'`, which would return all of the rows that have at least one "e" in the text; then your application would iterate over the rows and count the occurrences.

Comment: I'm looking for an SQL solution. That's what I'm doing now, but it's kind of slow. I thought using the SQL engine I'll get better performance

Comment: For the type of problem you are describing, faster performance generally comes from doing more computation ahead of time: e.g., counting the occurrences of each letter and storing that in the database.